# Why is there "is" in "... dīcitur is locus..."?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

Why is there **is** (it) in the following phrase from Ørberg's *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata*, page 118?

> *Ōstium* sīve *ōs* flūminis dīcitur **is** locus quō flumen in mare īnfluit.

Literally: By *Ostium* or *os* of the river is called **[it]** place where river in sea flows in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, *is, ea, id* is a **demonstrative pronoun** (like *hic, haec, hoc*; *ille, illa, illud*; etc.).

[Allen & Greenough §297](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-297.html) says the following about *is, ea, id*:

> ***Is* is a weaker demonstrative than the others and is especially common as a personal pronoun.** It does not denote any special object, but refers to one just mentioned, or to be afterwards explained by a relative. **Often it is merely a correlative to the relative quī:**—
>
> > *vēnit mihi obviam tuus puer, is mihi litterās abs tē reddidit* (Att. 2.1.1), your boy met me, he delivered to me a letter from you.
> >
> > *eum cōnsulem quī nōn dubitet* (Cat. 4.24), a consul who will not hesitate.

Your sample sentence demonstrates this correlation with a relative pronoun. You could translate as:

> **The** [or: "that"] place by which a river flows into the sea is called the *ostium* [doorway] or *os* [mouth] of the river.

Comment: +1! When I started writing my answer, I thought you'd be working on yours. And I guessed correctly that you'd take a different approach. :) I hope the different wordings of the same idea are useful...

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you call the English pronoun "it" as opposed to a demonstrative pronoun (if you are making such an opposition)?

Comment: I *think* it would be called (paradoxically) a personal pronoun, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That would make sense. It is syntactically practically a personal pronoun, much like a neuter counterpart to "he" and "she".

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where a word-by-word translation is misleading.
If you translate *is* as "that", it makes more sense.
And here you could translate it as "the".

In Latin you can use *is* like an adjective (e.g. *is locus*), but in English you can't (e.g. "it place" doesn't make sense, but "the place", "that place", or "this place" does).

The word *is* is not strictly necessary in the sentence, but it adds emphasis and gives a clear antecedent for the relative pronoun.